# How do I change the Font in BarChart Legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

Just wondering if anyone knows the proper Syntax to change the Text properties in the BarChart's ChartLegend. I cannot seem to figure out how to get Style[] to apply. Here is an example:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[{"John", "Mary", "Bob"}, Bottom]]

BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[Style[{"John", "Mary", "Bob"},
  FontFamily->"Courier"], Bottom]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

t.

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can do it without using `Map[]` as `Placed[]` takes a third optional argument for cases like this:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{"John", "Mary", "Bob"}, Bottom, Style[#, FontFamily -> "Courier"] &]]
```

Comment: Thank you. The third argument of `Placed[ ]` helps a lot.

Answer (score 9):

`Map[]` (i.e., `/@`) does the trick:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Courier"] & /@ {"John", "Mary", "Bob"}, Bottom]]
```

[image: bar chart example]

Answer (score 2):

One can also do this globally with [`` Legending`LegendContainer ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080536/618728):

```
SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend,
  Legending`LegendContainer -> (Framed @ Append[#, FontFamily -> "Mathematica6"] &)
];

BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
  ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartLegends -> Placed[{"John", "Mary", "Bob"}, Bottom]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works because the expression passed to the `LegendContainer` function has head `Style`, and `Append` therefore inserts the given style.