# SetOptions or other approach to imposing default styling of text in a BarChart Legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

Gustavo Delfino's [answer to an earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1412/8) showed that it is possible to use the third argument to `Placed` to format text in a `BarChart` legend as desired. For example, without this argument, the legend text in the example below would still be small and in Times, even though I have used `SetOptions` to style `BaseStyle` for `BarChart`, `Graphics`, etc.

```
BarChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 40], 
 ChartStyle -> Join[ConstantArray[Green, {39}], {Orange}], 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[Join[ConstantArray[None, {39}], {"Preliminary estimates"}], 
   Bottom, Style[#, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 14] &]]
```

[image]

Is there a way to set this globally? I’d like to enforce the font style of legends in a package, the way I have already done for the frame around the legend using [Mr.Wizard’s answer to an earlier question of mine on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080536/758485). I would have thought some setting of `BaseStyle` should work but these are the only (undocumented) options that `` Legending`GridLegend `` takes:

```
Options[Legending`GridLegend]

{"LegendPlacementFunction" -> Automatic, 
 LegendAppearance -> Automatic, 
 Legending`LegendContainer -> Automatic, 
 Legending`LegendHeading -> None, Legending`LegendImage -> Automatic, 
 Legending`LegendImage -> Automatic, 
 Legending`LegendLayout -> Automatic, 
 Legending`LegendPosition -> Automatic, 
 Legending`LegendSize -> Automatic}
```

Comment: If it's a package, then why not supply a custom barchart function that applies the styling in the definition, thereby hiding it from the end-user?

Comment: @R.M actually it is already a custom barchart function, but I'm trying to work out how to introduce simple legending into that function. Or I could just leave it to the successful tender for the contract to write the GUI.

Comment: makes more sense to leave it to the latter. They probably have that sorted.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand your requirements, but if you liked my prior answer that you referenced, why not use it here too?  Since the `LegendContainer` is applied to the legend you can use it to insert directives:

```
SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend, 
  Legending`LegendContainer -> (Append[#, {Red, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}] &) ]

BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2}}, 
  ChartLegends -> {"some", "text", "here"} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realised that this could be done as well as including the `Identity` trick in your last answer. (There's a blog post in here somewhere...)

Comment: @Verbeia similar use: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4586/121