# Selective inclusion of elements in BarChart Legend

Tags: plotting, legending

Further to [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6373/8), is there a concise way - amenable to automated setting in a package so that it can be accessed globally - to eliminate some legend item that would otherwise show? For example, in this example, I'd like to only show the orange rectangle and text "Preliminary estimates".

[image]

I tried a couple of replacement rules, by analogy with [belisarius’s answer for reversing stacked bar chart legends](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4579/8), such as the example below, but it doesn’t seem to make any difference.

```
BarChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 40], 
 ChartStyle -> Join[ConstantArray[Green, {39}], {Orange}], 
 ChartLegends -> 
 Placed[Join[ConstantArray[None, {39}], {"Preliminary estimates"}], 
 Bottom]] /. Pane[Row[x_]] :> Pane[Row[Last[x]]]
```

Comment: You could build a GUI that allows you to select which items are shown in a legend via checkboxes but the solutions below are more straight forward for specific cases.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch well, in principle I could, but in practice, that won't be me :)

Comment: ...as per this video: http://ibnhconsulting.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/railfreight-analysis.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the legends are typeset using a `Row` with two arguments (where the second argument is a separator which should be placed between the entries in the legend) but you're matching to a `Row` with only one argument. You could instead do something like

```
BarChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 40], 
 ChartStyle -> Join[ConstantArray[Green, {39}], {Orange}], 
 ChartLegends -> 
 Placed[Join[ConstantArray[None, {39}], {"Preliminary estimates"}], 
 Bottom]] /. Pane[Row[x_, ___]] :> Pane[Last[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Another way to selectively label entries in the `BarChart` is to do something like this

```
BarChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 40], 
 ChartStyle -> Join[ConstantArray[Green, {39}], {Orange}], 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Join[ConstantArray[
    None, {39}], {Placed["Preliminary estimates", Bottom]}]]
```

Comment: I just realised that some months ago I had come up with the second option you posted here and forgotten about it! It's definitely the cleanest option for my purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Use `MapAt` to apply the `Legended` and `Style` wrappers directly to the last item in the dataset:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 40];

data = MapAt[Legended[Style[#, Orange], "Preliminary estimate"] &, data, -1];

BarChart[data, ChartStyle -> Green, LegendAppearance -> "Row"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Of course, this got a lot easier in version 9:

```
BarChart[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.6], 40], 
 ChartStyle -> Join[ConstantArray[Green, {39}], {Orange}], 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[{Orange}, {"Estimate"}], Bottom]]
```

[image]

Comment: Definitely simpler.